# Экспорт истории чата telegram Pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня такая задача, пересылать сообщения приходящие от конкретного пользователя, в чат группы, и делать экспорт чата в файл, желательно в формате HTML, так как может приходить не только текст но и любые другие файлы. Вопрос во второй части , как делать экспорт чата при каждом новом сообщении с перезаписью файла ? Я так понимаю через get_chat_history, но как применить, пока не нашел решения, прошу помочь. Первую часть задачи я реализовал так и все отлично работает:

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler
from pyrogram.types import Message
from pyrogram import filters


api_id = ***

api_hash = "***"


client = Client("Duplicator", api_id, api_hash) 


#-90927119132 - ID  группы куда пересылать все сообщения
#623387511812 - ID пользователя ТГ только от которого пересылаем сообщения в группу

def all_message(client: Client, message: Message):
    message.forward(-90927119132)

client.add_handler(MessageHandler(all_message, filters.chat(chats=623387511812)))

#Экспорт истории группы -90927119132 в файл

client.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Добработал код, удалось научиться записывать в файл, но пока только текст, войсы отдельная песня как я понял, с ними буду разбираться в случае если будет коммерчески оправдано. Если посоветоваться, можно в лс)

```
#Дозаписываем сообщения в файл all_history.html
file = open("all_history.html", "a")
file.write(str(message.date) + '\n' + str(message.from_user.username) + '\n' + str(message.from_user.first_name) + ' ' + str(message.from_user.last_name) + '\n' + str(message.from_user.phone_number)  + '\n' + (message.text) + '\n' + '\n')
file.close()
```